# How to filter a pandas dataframe by dict column?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe df['serialnumber', 'basicinfo'], the column "basicinfo" is a dict {'name': xxx, 'model': xxx, 'studyid': xxx}.

Is there an easy way to filter this dataframe by the dict key "model"?

We can do this filtered by 'serialnumber' if it is integer:

```
df = df[df.serialnumber == <value>]
```

How to do that for dict column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You won't get the vectorized operations directly. But you could use `apply` to get the dictionary value from.

```
df = df[df.basicinfo.apply(lambda x: x['model'] == <value>)]
```