# Filtering pandas DataFrame with column of dictionaries using a particular key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a pandas DataFrame `df` that has one column `feats` made up of dictionaries. I am trying to filter the DataFrame to retain only rows that have a particular key called `color` in the column `feats`. Given below are few sample rows from that column.

```
{'color':'blue', 'width':'20','height':'100'}
{'color':'red', 'width':'15','height':'80'}
{'width':'25','height':'75'}
```

I tried a few things as shown below:

```
1. sub_df = df[['color' in x.keys() for x in df.feats]]
```

I got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'keys'

2. sub_df = df['color' in df['feats'].keys()]
```

I got this error:

```
KeyError: False
```

Using the suggestion in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43842206/how-to-filter-a-pandas-dataframe-by-dict-column), I tried the following, because I know all the possible values that the key takes.

```
3. sub_df1 = df[df.feats.apply(lambda x: x['color'] == 'blue')]
```

This is the error I get:

```
KeyError: 'color'
```

I believe this is all happening because some rows do not have the key `color`. So the question is how do I filter the DataFrame by overcoming this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `feats` column doesn't just contain dictionary, it has missing data masked as `None`. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'feats':[{'color':'blue', 'width':'20','height':'100'},
                            {'color':'red', 'width':'15','height':'80'},
                            {'width':'25','height':'75'}, 
                            None]})
```

To make sure we only check on `dict` type, we can use `isinstance`:

```
df[[isinstance(x, dict) and ('color' in x.keys()) for x in df.feats]]
```

Output:

```
                                               feats
0  {'color': 'blue', 'width': '20', 'height': '100'}
1    {'color': 'red', 'width': '15', 'height': '80'}
```

Comment: This works perfectly for me! Thanks a ton for saving me many more hours of trial and error.

Comment: you don't need x.keys(). This works:

df[[isinstance(x, dict) and ('color' in x) for x in df.feats]]