# KeyError when filter pandas dataframe by column with particular key:value pair

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-loc

My df looks like the following

| col1 | col_x |
| --- | --- |
| ... | {"key_x":"value1"} |
| ... | None |
| ... | {"key_x":"value2"} |

How to select all items with `{"key_x":"value1"}` in `col_x` ?

`col_x` values could be `dict` or `None`.

What I've tried:

```
df.loc[df['col_x']['key_x'] == 'value1']                           # KeyError: 'key_x'
```

```
df[~df['col_x'].isnull()].loc[df['col_x']['key_x'] == 'value1']    # KeyError: 'key_x'
```

```
df_ok = df[[isinstance(x, dict) and ('key_x' in x.keys()) for x in df.col_x]]
df_ok.loc[df_ok['col_x']['key_x'] == 'value1']                     # KeyError: 'key_x'
```

(last one syntax according [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64267909/filtering-pandas-dataframe-with-column-of-dictionaries-using-a-particular-key))

Comment: Is `col_x` actually a column of `dict` or are they `str`? My guess is it is an object column because of the `None` which is probably why you get the key error.

Comment: @It_is_Chris Dataframe columns/series can have mixed dtypes, even if the column is an `object` type it can contain both `str` and `dict` data (unlike numpy, where single-typing is enforced)

Comment: @G.Anderson Yes, correct.

Answer (score 2):

Lets us use `str.get` to yank the value from dictionary. The `str.get` method can handle null values as well as missing keys.

```
df[df['col_x'].str.get('key_x').eq('value1')]
```

---

```
                 col_x
0  {'key_x': 'value1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to apply dict.get on your dataframe column

```
df_ok.loc[df_ok['col_x'].apply(lambda x: x.get('key_x')) == 'value1'] 

    col1    col_x
0   ...     {'key_x': 'value1'}
```

As an aside, the syntax you used in your attempt that generated a `keyerror` was looking at the named indices of the *dataframe*, not the index of the values in the dataframe. For example, if I edit your df to give it string indices instead of numeric:

```
df.index=['key_x','key_none','key_y']
```

Then you can use that construction to find a row or rows where that index exists, but since that string doesn;t appear in the DF index, you get the keyerror

```
df.loc[df['col_x']['key_x']]

        col1    col_x
key_x   ...     {'key_x': 'value1'}
```